# Como dejar el footer abajo

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando hacer un footer, el cual ya lo tengo abajo, el problema es que cuando le quito zoom a google chrome, es decir de 100% a 30% queda como el que les pongo en la imagen y no se por que sea, me podrían ayudar por favor ??

[image: Como que se despega la imagen del fondo]

```
<footer class="footer footer-transparent ">
  <div>
      <div>
          <div>
              <ul>
                  <li class="list-inline-item "><a href="#" class="link-secondary">Política de privacidad</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
              Copyright © 2020
              <a href="# " class="link-secondary ">Veridos Identity Solutions</a>. Todos los derechos reservados.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </footer>

footer {
   border-top: 1px solid rgba(162, 163, 165, 0.2);
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #6e7582;
   position: absolute;``
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto responde tu duda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363408/como-posicionar-el-footer-al-final-de-la-p%c3%a1gina/365605#365605

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo !! me has ayudado mucho !!

Answer (score 1):

Para colocar el footer estatico al pie de pagina, te faltaba por agregar unas caracteristicas en el css, mira:

```
footer {
   border-top: 1px solid rgba(162, 163, 165, 0.2);
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #6e7582;
   botton: 0;

   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Puedes probar con esto, espero que te sirva! :D

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo intente con fixed pero me deja el footer siempre abajo, incluso cuando scrolleo

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer {
    clear: both;      
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(162, 163, 165, 0.2);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6e7582;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

Muy seguramente estes con un problema de bloques flotantes.
Para poder responderte a algo mas concreto, deverias compartir mas parte del codigo, no se cuales son tus intenciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo !!!